# Create graph to get device's x y z motion using LineRenderer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am getting the x y z position of the iOS device with values displaying on screen. I am trying to create graph like lines to determine those values using line renderer. Here is my code so far:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Main : MonoBehaviour 
{
  public LineRenderer lineRenderer;
  int len = 2;

  void Awake()        
  {
    lineRenderer = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
  }

  void Update() 
  {
    if (Input.touchCount > 0 && m_HitTransform != null)
    {
      Debug.Log("Touch began");
      var touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
      if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began || touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
      {
        var screenPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint(touch.position);
        ARPoint point = new ARPoint
        {
          x = screenPosition.x,
          y = screenPosition.y
        };
        Vector3 pos3d = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(
          m_HitTransform.position.x, 
          m_HitTransform.position.y, 
          m_HitTransform.position.z));
        lineRenderer.SetVertexCount(len);
        lineRenderer.SetPosition(len - 1, pos3d);
        len++;
        text.text = string.Format("X:{0:0.######} Y:{1:0.######} Z:{2:0.######}", 
          m_HitTransform.position.x, 
          m_HitTransform.position.y, 
          m_HitTransform.position.z);

        // prioritize reults types
        ARHitTestResultType[] resultTypes = 
        {
          ARHitTestResultType.ARHitTestResultTypeExistingPlaneUsingExtent, 
          // if you want to use infinite planes use this:
          //ARHitTestResultType.ARHitTestResultTypeExistingPlane,
          ARHitTestResultType.ARHitTestResultTypeHorizontalPlane,
          ARHitTestResultType.ARHitTestResultTypeFeaturePoint
        };
        foreach (ARHitTestResultType resultType in resultTypes)
        {
          if (HitTestWithResultType(point, resultType)) return;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Pleaso, do not say "It's not working". Say what is your expected result, what are you getting and in which context.

Comment: well I'm expecting a line to be created which moves like a graph according to device motion. I am able to get the xyz values. right now the line is just sitting in centre